# Linear Hashing: Fast Method for finding 'min' and 'max'

Tags: c++11, max, min

i implemented a min() and max() function for my Linear Hashtable, but i have little performance issue, because i implemented it straight forward.
I just assume that the first element that has been found is the min/mix and then i compare the rest of the elements against it. Is there a faster way
to find the min/max in a hash table? I couldn't find anything in my books.
My second approach was to write every value in an array and then look through this, but i don't think this is faster.

Comment: Alternatively, track min and max elements as items are inserted into the table.

Comment: @AndyG: That would make deletions fairly expensive.

Comment: @BillLynch: O(n) per deletion versus O(n) per lookup. There's tradeoffs either way, all depends on use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic hash table is not a sorted list of elements. So it's going to be an `O(n)` operation to find the `min()` and `max()` of a given table.

Comment: Ok, so there is no faster way.

Answer (score 0):

In agreement with Bill Lynch, we'll have to spend `O(n)` time at least once, however we can be as lazy as possible:

- Store `min` and `max` alongside the table
- So long as user is doing updates, update `min` and `max` as necessary
- Upon deletion, check if deleted item is `min` or `max`, if so, set a flag to `true` indicating that min or max has changed. If the flag is already set, no need to check against current min/max
- Upon lookup for min/max, check your flag. If it has not been set, you can use your cached value of min or max. If it has been set, spend `O(n)` time setting them again.

Now we will only spend `O(n)` time when we need to, versus `O(n)` time every single time someone requests min or max. If there are many more insertions than deletions, you will in general see `O(1)` lookup time.

Comment: That sounds interesting, i will give it a try.